# Kotlin extension function for nullable types ONLY

Tags: kotlin, extension-methods, type-systems

Examine this code:

```kotlin
fun f(nullString: String?, nonNullString: String) {
    nullString.ext() // Error: Only safe (?.) or non-null asserted (!!.) calls are allowed on a nullable receiver of type String?
    nullString.nullExt() // OK, nullabilities match
    nonNullString.ext() // OK, nullabilities match
    nonNullString.nullExt() // Expected error: nullExt is only applicable to String?
}
```

I would like to write two function signatures that **makes the first and last function call not compile.**

This makes the first line a compile error, but the last line still compiles:

```kotlin
fun String.ext(): Unit = TODO()
fun String?.nullExt(): Unit = TODO()
```

As far as I understand this works because "`String` extends `String?`", so defining an extension on `String?` is similar to defining one on `CharSequence`. Is there a way to prevent this from compiling?

Comment: I could be wrong, but I don't think this is possible without writing some kind of compiler plugin or linter, because it would violate the Liskov substitution principle to disallow it. Also, the compiler actively tries to smart-cast nullable variables to non-nullable where logically possible, so you'd have to fight with that, too.

Comment: Smart cast doesn't seem like a problem, the point of the function I'm trying to write is to make `?: error()` chainable: `a.b().c().error("").d().e()`, and I want to be able to fail when `c()` is already non-null (e.g. by project evolution).

Comment: I don't think Liskov is in play here, because this is a statically bound overload resolution choice, actually that gives me an idea...

Comment: So by `error("")` you mean like `compileErrorIfNonNullable()`?

Comment: Yes, that was exactly what I was thinking.

Answer (score 2):

A possible solution is to forbid the compiler to pick the "super" implementation, by declaring a more specific one:

```kotlin
fun String.ext(): Unit = TODO()
fun String?.nullExt(): Unit = TODO()

@Deprecated(
    message = "nullExt is only applicable to nullable receivers.",
    level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR,
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith("")
)
fun String.nullExt(): Unit =
    error("This should never be called.")
```

Note: `String!` will resolve to `String` overload.

---

A real use case in case anyone is wondering:

```
fun <T : Any?> T?.orError(message: String): T & Any =
    this ?: error(message)

@Deprecated(
    message = "orError is only applicable to nullable receivers.",
    level = DeprecationLevel.ERROR,
    replaceWith = ReplaceWith("")
)
fun <T : Any> T.orError(message: String): Nothing =
    error("This should never be called.")
```

we wouldn't want `somethingNonNull.orError()` because in that case `orError()` will never execute and therefore it is dead code.

Comment: Ingenious! (Which of course means it'll need some very clear comments to explain what's going on to anyone else reading the code who isn't as smart as you :-)

Comment: @gidds `// See https://stackoverflow.com/a/76324369/253468` ;)
Even I added it for myself https://github.com/TWiStErRob/net.twisterrob.cinema/blob/1ce6590eda622cebe5131281f727735f22af6312/Heroku/shared/src/main/kotlin/net/twisterrob/cinema/shared/orError.kt#L6